# Default NSAutoreleasePool in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autorelease

I asked about [NSAutoreleasePool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138142/whats-the-magic-of-nsautoreleasepool-in-objective-c-cocoa-framework), and understand that I need explicitly allocate autorelease pool in this case.

```
int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Create an array
    NSArray *month = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@ ... nill];

    [pool drain];
}
```

In my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138112/getting-date-info-into-an-array-in-objective-c-cocoa-framework), I don't need release `NSArray` as it will be autoreleased.

```
- (NSArray*) getTodayArray
{

    ...

    NSArray *res = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: year, month, nil];

    return res;
}
```

In order to be the object autoreleased even though I didn't make any NSAutorelease, there should be some `default` autorelease pool allocated in Cocoa. The Xcode generated main function is pretty simple.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

Is it correct? If so, when and how it's allocated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main thread's `NSRunLoop` creates and destroys an `NSAutoreleasePool` every time it "loops".  Note, however, that when you split off any background thread, you need to create an autorelease pool for it (since secondary threads, by default, do not have active run loops).

Answer (score 1):

NSApplicationMain creates NSAutoreleasePool instance at first in NSApplicationMain. And as @Dave said, NSRunLoop creates and drains NSAutoreleasePool instance every loop.

As you know, it is not the exactly same between Apple's implementation and GNUstep implementation but these are similar.

[GNUstep libs/gui/trunk/Source/Functions.m](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/gui/trunk/Source/Functions.m?revision=HEAD&view=markup)

```
int
NSApplicationMain(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  NSDictionary      *infoDict;
  NSString              *mainModelFile;
  NSString      *className;
  Class         appClass;
  CREATE_AUTORELEASE_POOL(pool);
```